# How are discord bots online?

Tags: discord, bots

How are discord bots online? Is there any API call I need to do to make my bot online? I just want to use the API, I don't want to use any libraries.

Comment: Without a library it's going to be hard. It isn't a HTTP REST API endpoint you just call and your bot comes online. The communication to the API is based on websocket connection.

Comment: any reference link(s)?

Comment: https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway; Implementation: see source code from the discord libraries. "The API for interacting with Gateways is complex and fairly unforgiving, therefore it's highly recommended you read all of the following documentation before writing a custom implementation."
It's best if you just use a library.

Comment: from the very brief testing I did where the bot was running on my local machine, it was online as soon as it connected through whatever the hello world example used and went offline every time my code crashed.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know about the Discord bot, I know this is not possible.
When you make a disc bot, it looks like a member. The only difference is that a series of features such as having a bot verification and having a dedicated roll.
Discord gives you a bot token that can be used to control the bot and enter the bot. You can write a code that keeps the bot online.

**This was my information about the Discord bot. I may be wrong and someone may have more accurate and useful information.**